# Rademacher Complexity of the Composition with an Indicator

Tags: complexity-classes, machine-learning

Consider the statistical learning setting where you have an arbitrary hypothesis space $\mathcal{H}$, a data space $\mathcal{Z}$, and a bounded loss function $\ell: \mathcal{H}\times \mathcal{Z} \rightarrow [0,1]$. Further, for $c\in(0,1)$, let $\mathcal{F}_c$ be the function class defined by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_c := \{ z \mapsto  \mathbb{I}\{\ell(h,z) \leq c\}: h \in \mathcal{H}\}. 
\end{align}
**Question.** Is it in any way possible to relate the Rademacher complexity of the function class $\mathcal{F}_c$, to that of $\ell \circ \mathcal{H}:= \{z\mapsto \ell(h,z): h \in \mathcal{H}\}$?
My goal is to show that when the complexity of the latter class is small, so is the complexity of the former.

**Rademacher Complexity.** The Rademacher complexity of a function class $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{R}_n(\mathcal{F}) := \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i f(z_i)\right], \quad n \in \mathbb{N},
\end{align}
where $(\sigma_i,z_i)$ are i.i.d. random variables with $(\sigma_i)$ having a Rademacher distribution.

**Failed Attempt.** There are results on the Rademacher complexity of the composition of functions, but these typically rely on some Lipschitzness properties, which do not hold for our function class $\mathcal{F}_c$ since we compose with an indicator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, composing a threshold function with a function class can arbitrarily increase the Rademacher complexity (so the answer to your question is negative). Let $\Omega$ be a finite set, $|\Omega|=N$, and let $F=[-a,a]^\Omega$ be the set of all functions from $\Omega$ to $[-a,a]$.
When $N\gg n$, the Rademacher complexity (either empirical or expected) of $F$ will be $\Theta(a)$. Let $F'$ be $F$ composed with the sign function; now $F'=\{-1,1\}^\Omega$ and its Rademacher complexity in this regime is $\Theta(1)$. Since $a>0$ can be taken arbitrarily small, this shows that the multiplicative gap can be arbitrarily large.